# Unable to trap "CTRL+C" within kickstart "%pre" bash script

Tags: centos, rhel, kickstart, installer-anaconda

I'm using an interactive pre-installation bash script in a CentOS-7 kickstart image.
I was trying to use "trap" to catch user <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (SIGINT) and run some code as follows:

```
trap_ctrl_c() {

 #Some code....

}

trap "trap_ctrl_c" SIGINT
```

While simulating the script (running it from the command line) works/traps perfectly, It seems like during the kickstart installation the signal is trapped by anaconda and ignored.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/175241/edit) your question and make it clear by formatting code part(use <Ctrl>+<K>) and remove unnecessary `*`s. Thank you

Comment: The last command of `trap_ctrl_c()` is something like `exit 0` or `exit $?`, right?

Comment: @pidosaurus - No. the last command is some kind of assiment to a variable, afterwhich it should "return 0" natively. The thing is that trap_ctrl_c() is not triggered by pressing the ctrl+c within the %pre stage, unlike when running the script from the command line